# openni_grabber.h not found while using PCL

Tags: cmake, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, openni

I'm using PCL to connect to a Kinect camera. Right now, I'm just trying to build the OpenNi Grabber tutorial found [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php). While building I'm getting an error that openni_grabber.h is not found.

```
fatal error: 'pcl/io/openni_grabber.h' file not found
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
```

I checked the directory in question and the file is indeed missing, but I'm not sure why. Is there an install option that I'm missing?

I have installed OpenNi using Homebrew and [this formula.](https://github.com/totakke/homebrew-openni) I am using the Kinect v1.

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot find a place in the tutorial where it suggests to include files by **absolute path** like `usr/local/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/io/openni_grabber.h`. Moreover, this is not an absolute path because leading '/' is missing.

Comment: Oops. I tried first by copying directly from the tutorial. After trying several times with this, I used the absolute path as a last resort, and I accidentally copied this version into my question. The problem occurs either way, as the file doesn't seem to exist in the pcl/io/ include directory.

Comment: Looks like your PCL installation lacks of the specified header: https://answers.ros.org/question/35514/where-is-pclioopenni_grabberh/

Comment: Indeed, openni_grabber.h is missing. But I found openni2_grabber.h